# Jquery on click select button with nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my HTML. I want to show my table row when this button is clicked and change the `i` class. however, I can't seem to select the inner element.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-outline-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>  



<script>
    $("body").on("click", "button > i.fa-plus", function () {
                    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='row'><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");            
                    $(this).attr("class", "fa fa-minus");
                    $('#row').hide(); 
                    $('#row').fadeIn();
                });
</script>
```

Here is full code, it's a nested table

```
 <table class="table table-striped text-center" style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].UAP)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].Celula.Nome)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].Referencia.Nome)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].ObjectivoHora)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].CelulaTipo.Nome)</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Matrizes)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Geometrias != null)
                                {
                                <button type="button" class="btn-outline-warning">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </button>
                                    <div id="tblGeometrias"  style="display:none">
                                        <table class="table table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].Geometrias.SingleOrDefault().Id)</th>
                                                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].Geometrias.SingleOrDefault().Componente)</th>
                                                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].Geometrias.SingleOrDefault().ToleranciaInferior)</th>
                                                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Matrizes[0].Geometrias.SingleOrDefault().ToleranciaSuperior)</th>
                                                    <th></th>                                 
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach (var geometria in item.Geometrias)
                                                {
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => geometria.Id)</td>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => geometria.Componente)</td>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => geometria.ToleranciaInferior)</td>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => geometria.ToleranciaSuperior)</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a asp-page="./Geometrias/Edit" asp-route-id="@geometria.Id" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>                                                            
                                                            <a asp-page="./Geometrias/Delete" asp-route-id="@geometria.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a>
                                                        </td>                                                   
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UAP.Nome)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celula.Nome)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Referencia.Nome)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ObjectivoHora)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CelulaTipo.Nome)</td>
                            <td>

                                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
                                <a asp-page="./Geometrias/Create" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"> X-R</a>
                                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I have updated my answer, this is an asp.net core application

this is just some nested tables and i'm trying to show the nested table with jquery

Comment: that's just to give a fade effect to the content because the content isn't hidden yet

Comment: see updated answer, i posted whole code

Comment: Yeah so related to the id thing, `after("<tr id='row'>...` is going to be creating new rows with duplicate ids.  That's not valid HTML by web standards.  That needs to be a class.

Comment: i see ill change this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (comments in code explaining changes)

```js
$("body").on("click", "button > i.fa-plus,button > i.fa-minus", function() { // might as well bind to both or change selector to button > i.fa (if your icon has fa as that class doesn't change)
  var $icon = $(this); // the clicked icon

  if ($icon.hasClass('fa-plus')) { // if plus icon pressed
    var $newRow = $("<tr class='row-added'><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $icon.next().html() + "</td></tr>"); // create new row with a class instead of id (ids should be unique and this can be added multiple times)

    $icon.closest("tr").after($newRow.hide()); // add your new row hidden

    $newRow.fadeIn(); // fadeIn the new row
  } else { // if minus icon pressed
    $icon.closest("tr").next('.row-added').remove(); // remove next row (if it was added)
  }

  $icon.toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus"); // change the icon

});
```

```css
.fa-plus:before {
  content: '+';
  display:inline-block;
}

.fa-minus:before {
  content: '-';
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan = '1000'><button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>test</span></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or bind the event to the button:

```js
$("body").on("click", "button", function() { 
  var $icon = $(this).find('i.fa'); // the clicked icon

  if ($icon.hasClass('fa-plus')) { // if plus icon pressed
    var $newRow = $("<tr class='row-added'><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $icon.next().html() + "</td></tr>"); // create new row with a class instead of id (ids should be unique and this can be added multiple times)

    $icon.closest("tr").after($newRow.hide()); // add your new row hidden

    $newRow.fadeIn(); // fadeIn the new row
  } else { // if minus icon pressed
    $icon.closest("tr").next('.row-added').remove(); // remove next row (if it was added)
  }

  $icon.toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus"); // change the icon

});
```

```css
.fa-plus:before {
  content: '+';
  display:inline-block;
}

.fa-minus:before {
  content: '-';
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan = '1000'><button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>test</span></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, i add debugger however the function is not triggered.

Comment: works in the snippet - see updated  example - you have to click on the icon as that is what you bound your event to.  You would probably be better to bind the event to the button and then find the icon in the click event (see second example)

Comment: yes pretty much that, i binded on button instead and worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).next().html()
```

This line will not return anything.  In the context of your click handler, the `this` is the `<i>`, which as no siblings.  This should be the following to use your button.

```
$(this).closest('button').next().html()
//or
$(this).parent().next().html()
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposl is:

```js
$("body").on("click", "button > i.fa-plus", function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    tr.after("<tr class='row'><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
    tr.next('.row').fadeIn();
});
$("body").on("click", "button > i.fa-minus", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").next('.row').remove();
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" >


<button type="button" class="btn-outline-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<table class="table table-striped text-center" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>UAP</th>
        <th>Celula.Nome</th>
        <th>Referencia.Nome</th>
        <th>ObjectivoHora</th>
        <th>CelulaTipo.Nome</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn-outline-warning">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="tblGeometrias"  style="display:none">
                <table class="table table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Componente</th>
                        <th>ToleranciaInferior</th>
                        <th>ToleranciaSuperior</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>geometria.Id</td>
                        <td>Componente</td>
                        <td>ToleranciaInferior</td>
                        <td>ToleranciaSuperior</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="./Geometrias/Edit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
                            <a href="./Geometrias/Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>UAP.Nome</td>
        <td>Celula.Nome</td>
        <td>Referencia.Nome</td>
        <td>ObjectivoHora</td>
        <td>CelulaTipo.Nome</td>
        <td>
            <a href="./Edit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
            <a href="./Geometrias/Create" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"> X-R</a>
            <a href="./Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the inner element you mean the (i class="fa fa-plus")
First I would not use body as selector, it's recommended to make the selection as specific as possible.

Possible selection using button, tr, or at least Table.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='row'><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + 
                $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");            
                $(this).attr("class", "fa fa-minus");
                $('#row').fadeIn();
});
```

If by inside element you mean element inside tr, then post your full html so I can check where is the issue.

Also, I'd suggest hiding some where before the click event so clicking fa-plus would only fadeIn, and if you have fa-minus would fadeOut or hide.

Hope that helps

Comment: i tried this but function is not triggered when i use debugger

Comment: you can use $(this).children(".fa-plus") to access i  fa-plus, I've update it after saw your full HTML. And If you send me the client side generated html. happy to check that for you as well